# command not found: django

Tags: python, django, azure, path

I installed django using

```
pip install Django
```

My result was

```
Requirement already satisfied: Django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.11.14)
```

When I run

```
django --version
```

I get

```
zsh: command not found: django
```

Here is the entire script:

```
➜  frameworks git:(master) ✗ pip install Django
Requirement already satisfied: Django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.11.14)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Django) (2018.5)
azure-cli-core 2.0.41 has requirement pyyaml~=4.2b4, but you'll have pyyaml 3.12 which is incompatible.
azure-cli-core 2.0.41 has requirement tabulate<=0.8.2,>=0.7.7, but you'll have tabulate 0.7.5 which is incompatible.
azure-cli-core 2.0.41 has requirement wheel==0.30.0, but you'll have wheel 0.31.0 which is incompatible.
rainbowstream 1.3.7 has requirement requests==2.5.3, but you'll have requests 2.18.4 which is incompatible.
flask 1.0.2 has requirement click>=5.1, but you'll have click 4.1 which is incompatible.
cli-helpers 1.0.2 has requirement tabulate[widechars]>=0.8.2, but you'll have tabulate 0.7.5 which is incompatible.
cookiecutter 1.6.0 has requirement click>=5.0, but you'll have click 4.1 which is incompatible.
cycli 0.7.6 has requirement prompt-toolkit==0.57, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 1.0.15 which is incompatible.
azure-cli-acs 2.1.3 has requirement pyyaml~=4.2b4, but you'll have pyyaml 3.12 which is incompatible.
azure-cli-interactive 0.3.25 has requirement pyyaml~=4.2b4, but you'll have pyyaml 3.12 which is incompatible.
azure-cli-extension 0.1.0 has requirement wheel==0.30.0, but you'll have wheel 0.31.0 which is incompatible.
azure-cli-container 0.2.1 has requirement pyyaml~=4.2b4, but you'll have pyyaml 3.12 which is incompatible.
legit 1.0.1 has requirement click==6.7, but you'll have click 4.1 which is incompatible.
➜  frameworks git:(master) ✗ django --version
zsh: command not found: django
➜  frameworks git:(master) ✗ django version
zsh: command not found: django
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command line utility named `django`. You should use `django-admin`:

```
$ django-admin version
1.11.14
```